# Chilkat SFTP Upload of zero byte file return value

Tags: file-upload, sftp, chilkat

When i upload a zero byte file using Chilkat SFTP, it returns a value of zero as if unsuccessful even though the file has uploaded successfully.

I expected the return value to be 1. Here is the pertinent Visual FoxPro code. As you can see, I have commented out the line that captures the return value and just run the upload method which is working.

```
        lcHandle = loSftp.OpenFile(lcRemoteDir+lcFileName+".DONE","writeOnly","createTruncate")
        IF loSftp.LastMethodSuccess = 1
            *lnSuccess = loSftp.UploadFile(lcHandle,IIF(!EMPTY(lcZipFile),lcZipFile,lcArchive+lcFileName+".DONE"))
loSftp.UploadFile(lcHandle,IIF(!EMPTY(lcZipFile),lcZipFile,lcArchive+lcFileName+".DONE"))
            loSftp.CloseHandle(lcHandle)
        ENDIF
```

This is the line that creates the zero byte file:

```
    STRTOFILE("", lcFolder+lcFileName+'.DONE')
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the relevant code from your program.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an older version of Chilkat, check to see if updating to the latest version solves the problem. It's likely the problem was already solved.

Comment: Updated to the latest version and problem still exists